# Does webkitgtk support flash?

Tags: flash, webkit, gtk

Does webkitgtk support flash? If yes then I need an example code to play a flash file. Wonder if we can play a flash file in WebView.

Comment: Yes! what I use is Ubuntu11.10 and it's version of webkit is kde.

Comment: But I don't know how to use the plugin.Should I insert plugin into my code?And what should I do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! I didn't find Flash Plugin here:/usr/lib/ .And  can you tell me the location or directory of the WebKitGtK's plugins?

Comment: This is my "include" files:#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
and gcc code:gcc webkit.c -o webkit `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 webkitgtk-3.0`

Comment: I found libflashplayer.so here:                              /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

Comment: I didn't find directory /usr/lib/flashplugin-nofree/                     and I found nothing except libexec in the directory:/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0/

Comment: I'm so grateful for your help!And I will do as you say.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I'm a new webkit and  linux user and I can't  solve my problems with your answer. Can you help me ?How to let webkit know the path of the libflashplayer.so and then use it?